# Ubuntu Core and third-party hardware and drivers

Tags: ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, electron

I'm doing tests to create a POS system in a very general stack (Ubuntu Core + Electron.js (snap) + mir-kiosk) and hardware (Raspberry PI 3 B+ + Display Touch + Printer Epson + Qr Code Scanner + Cam).

I have third-party hardware and drivers E.g (printer, scanner..), I still do not know how to install them in Ubuntu Core. What comes to my mind is to have another device with Ubuntu Server and be able to install all the devices there and expose them to the network. But I guess we would lose the benefit of creating a "native" app with electron.js because we can not access the new devices. By having a point of sale system based on the cloud it would be better to create a web application instead of a native application with electron.js?

I appreciate any suggestion, we are only doing pilot tests, nothing in particular yet, the idea is to create advanced POS System that fits the requirements of the store, with access to multiple services in the cloud and based on the Internet of things.